# How to look for the difference between two large files in tcl?

Tags: file, file-io, compare, tcl

I have two files, the some of the contents of these might be common in both. (say file `A.txt` and file `B.txt`)
Both the files are sorted files. 
I need to get the difference of file `A.txt` and `B.txt`, ie, a file `C.txt` which has contents of A except the common contents in both.

I used the typical search and print algorithm, ie, took a line from `A.txt`, searched in `B.txt`, if found, print nothing in `C.txt`, else print that line in `C.txt`.
But, I am dealing with files with huge # of contents, and thus, it throws error: `failed to load too many files`. (Though it works fine for smaller files)

Can anybody suggest more efficient way of getting `C.txt`?
Script to be used: TCL only!

Comment: Too bad for your "tcl only" restriction: this is just what [`comm`](http://man.cx/comm) is for.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `too many files` error is an indication that you're not closing a channel, probably in the `B.txt` scanner. Fixing that is probably your first goal. If you've got Tcl 8.6, try this helper procedure:

```
proc scanForLine {searchLine filename} {
    set f [open $filename]
    try {
        while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
            if {$line eq $searchLine} {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    } finally {
        close $f
    }
}
```

However, if one of the files is small enough to fit into memory reasonably, you'd be far better reading it into a hash table (e.g., a dictionary or array):

```
set f [open B.txt]
while {[gets $f line]} {
    set B($line) "any dummy value; we'll ignore it"
}
close $f

set in [open A.txt]
set out [open C.txt w]
while {[gets $in line]} {
    if {![info exists B($line)]} {
        puts $out $line
    }
}
close $in
close $out
```

This is *much* more efficient, but depends on `B.txt` being small enough.

If both `A.txt` and `B.txt` are too large for that, you are probably best doing some sort of processing by stages, writing things out to disk in-between. This is getting rather more complex!

```
set filter [open B.txt]
set fromFile A.txt

for {set tmp 0} {![eof $filter]} {incr tmp} {
    # Filter by a million lines at a time; that'll probably fit OK
    for {set i 0} {$i < 1000000} {incr i} {
        if {[gets $filter line] < 0} break
        set B($line) "dummy"
    }

    # Do the filtering
    if {$tmp} {set fromFile $toFile}
    set from [open $fromFile]
    set to [open [set toFile /tmp/[pid]_$tmp.txt] w]
    while {[gets $from line] >= 0} {
        if {![info exists B($line)]} {
            puts $to $line
        }
    }
    close $from
    close $to

    # Keep control of temporary files and data
    if {$tmp} {file delete $fromFile}
    unset B
}
close $filter
file rename $toFile C.txt
```

Warning! I've not tested this code…